# Change indent for function calls in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: indentation, emacs-lisp-mode

*While writing the question I found a viable workaround solution for myself, so I am posting it as Q&A. I am leaving the question open, because my workaround does not allow to set the* amount *by which things are indented.*

By default Emacs indents function calls as

```
(function-name (first-argument)
               (second-argument))
```

This is mostly fine, unless nesting gets very deep or if `function-name` is on the long side. Then it becomes preferable to put all arguments on a separate line, which Emacs indents as

```
(function-name
 (first-argument)
 (second-argument))
```

This I find extremely ugly, because it makes code hard to read, when arguments are barely indented *at all*.

I `could` add a file local variable `-*- lisp-indent-offset: 4 -*-` to get more readable

```
(function-name
    (first-argument)
    (second-argument))
```

but this then would not affect only functions but would also produce the very much *not* well-readable

```
(let ((a (first-argument))
         (b (second-argument)))
    (function-name a b))
```

or for quoted data, equally bad,

```
(setq data '(data1
                data2
                data3))
```

This part is probably the most tricky, since Emacs has no fully
reliable way to distinguish it from a quoted expression

```
(setq expression '(function-name
                      (first-argument)
                      (second-argument)))
```

which I assume is the reason for the default behavior.

Is there any option, short of writing my own indent function, that would allow Emacs Lisp functions to be indented more deeply, *without* overriding the explicitly declared behavior for macros?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

The best I can currently think of is

```
(advice-add #'function-get :around #'my--get-lisp-indent-function)
(defun my--get-lisp-indent-function (oldfun symbol propname &rest r)
  (let ((value (apply oldfun symbol propname r)))
    (cond ((not (eq propname 'lisp-indent-function))
           value)
          ((and (null value)
                (functionp symbol))
           0)
          (t value))))
```

Which *mostly* fulfills the requirement.

I also like to add some customizations, like

```
(put 'format 'lisp-indent-function 1)
(put 'cl-loop 'lisp-indent-function 0)
```

### Remarks

##### function-get

Cannot advise 'get, because 'get has its own opcode in compiled code and thus isn't affected by advice.

##### (functionp symbol)

If always returning the modified value, it would cause incorrect indentation of quoted data lists and binding forms

```
(setq data '(data1
              data2))
(let ((var1 val1)
       (var2 val2))
  ...)
```

##### lisp-indent-function -> 0

Only viable value is 0. For comparison:

```
;; 0 -> correct, but slightly low indent
(function-name (arg1)
               (arg2))
(function-name
  (arg1)
  (arg2)
  
;; defun -> incorrect
(function-name (arg1)
  (arg2))

;; most-positive-fixnum -> weird, but acceptable?
(function-name
    (arg1)
    (arg2)) ;; Nice!
(function-name (arg1)
    (arg2)) ;; Decidedly not nice.
```