# Indenting inside a sexp "as is the containiing sexp were not there"

Tags: indentation

I need to customize `lisp-indent-function` for a particular type of functions in such a way that it would indent lines "as if the function call were not there"; for instance say that I want to indent this way the args of a function called emph

```lisp
(fictional-print x y z
  a b c (emph d
  e f g))
```

as opposed to what the default implementation does

```lisp
(fictional-print x y z
  a b c (emph d
              e f g))
```

(`fictional-print` has `'defun` indentation.)

Comment: Um, why? The desired indentation looks horrible!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change indent for function calls in Emacs Lisp?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69321/change-indent-for-function-calls-in-emacs-lisp)